# Phonegap http GET request returns empty string

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, phonegap-build

So, I'm trying to call my server `server.com/api` for some data from inside a Phonegap Android App. I'm calling it through `HTTP Get` method.

Everything works fine on `localhost`, `file://` and even on `server.com`. I've also added my domain to `config.xml`.

And now code:

**Server `PHP`**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
```

**JS**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://server.com/api", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if ( xhr.readyState == 4 ) {
    if ( xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0 ) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      alert("NOPE");
    }
  }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

**config.xml**

```
<access origin="http://server.com"/>

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />
```

Any idea is welcomed,

Cheers!

**EDIT**

I did tried a bunch of combinations for origin="" (e.g. "*", "*.server.com", etc)

Comment: please see this answer:
[Phonegap build server not working whitelist plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651646/phonegap-build-server-not-working-whitelist-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

something to try here would be to change the access origin to

```
<access origin="http://server.com/*"/>
```

I've had that issue on some PhoneGap apps and it helped to add that * in the end...

Comment: it seems that before 3.x the syntax involved a * at the end but it is no more the case. @xnamex, you could make a test with access origin="*", even if that's not what you want at the end,it will help to see if it is related to this parameter.

Comment: @QuickFix I've tried that, before asking the question. I should've mention that. Editing

Comment: do you wait the deviceready event before you do the get? And another stupid questions : have you tried to access your server from the browser on the phone?, Did you try to display the status code from the httprequest? Did you watch the console if there are error logs?

Comment: The request is being executed on a button click.

1. I listen to the `onload` event, is there a difference between deviceready?

2. As I mentioned, localhost, file://, server.com all of them works on desktop browser aswell as mobile.

3. I did not logged the status, but I figured it's either 200 or 0, since the `if` it's evaluating to true.

4. Nope, no errors.

Comment: in your edit you say that you tried origin="", but with empty string you denied access to all domain. try with origin="*"

Comment: did you try to control with if the httpRequest is sent from your phone to server and what is the response?

Comment: check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651646/phonegap-build-server-not-working-whitelist-plugin